# Creating User in esxi 6.5 and assigning role

Tags: permissions, esxi

I am using vmware 6.5 and trying to create another user. All KB article on vmware I found are for older version e.g. esxi 5 or 5.5

In 6.5 I have managed to create user and create role, however I do not see any way to assign this role to user.

As per two images attached.

How do I attach new user to role?

[image: Click here to see image - Create Role]

[image: Click here to see image - Create User]

Answer (score 51):

I was trying to figure this out as well and found the solution. It's a little strange assigning the user permissions, as it's in a different location from the tab where you create users and roles.

If you got back the default host view and click on the Actions button on the top of the view and go to

Actions -> Permissions

From there you click Add User, and then pick the user account you created and the role you want.

[image]

Comment: Man, that was definitely non-intuitive.

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous UX… Lord almighty! I would've NEVER figured it out organically! :X

Comment: I am flabbergasted at the poor quality of the ESXi application UI. It's almost enough to not use it... To boot, the VMWare documentation is horrendous. It's so disorganized and inconsistent, it makes me really sad ;(

Comment: This also works on ESXi 6.7

Comment: This is still the terrible UI in version 7.  Wow.